# How to fetch status from database to show

Tags: mysql, flutter, dart, listview

I want to fetch status from database and show in listview as text but status which i store in database is number, how can i set those status as text?

```
0 = start
2 = pending approval
3 = Approved
```

```
                    return ListView.builder(
                        itemCount: problemlist.length,
                        itemBuilder: ((context, index) {
                           problemModel problem = problemlist[index];
                           return Card(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                            child: ListTile(
                              leading: CircleAvatar(
                                 backgroundImage: NetworkImage(
                                  'http://192.168.1.5/skc/Problem_image/${problem.image}',
                                  ),
                                 ),
                              title: Text(
                                problem.name_surname,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 19),
                              ),
                               subtitle: Text(
                                problem.status,
                                style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 17),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        }));
```

Answer (score 0):

The straigthforward method is to create an helper function to change the type of your value.

```
    String getStatusText(int statusCode) {
      switch (statusCode) {
        case 0:
          return 'Start';
        case 2:
          return 'Pending Approval';
        case 3:
          return 'Approved';
        default:
          return 'Unknown Status';
      }
    }
```

Or later on if you have more complex object that not only has a status and manage directly custom types in your app

```
    class Status {
      final int code;
      final String text;
    
      Status._(this.code, this.text);
    
      factory Status.fromCode(int statusCode) {
        switch (statusCode) {
          case 0:
            return Status._(statusCode, 'Start');
          case 2:
            return Status._(statusCode, 'Pending Approval');
          case 3:
            return Status._(statusCode, 'Approved');
          default:
            return Status._(statusCode, 'Unknown Status');
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

create a status enum

```
enum StatusEnum{
      Start,
      PendingApproval,
      Approved,
    }
```

which can be accessed through

```
StatusEnum.values[i].name
```

where 'i' is status code